# How can I set value for extra field on Eloquent pivot table

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

$recourse->pivot->field = 'value';

gives error: Indirect modification of overloaded property

Comment: Show the code, it just works.

Comment: `$product = Product::find($item->id);
$order->pivot->price = '1.234';
$order->product()->save($product);`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`pivot` is available only in the context of a relation:

```
// won't work
$model = Model::first();
$model->pivot; // null

// will work
$anotherModel = AnotherModel::first();
$relatedModel = $anotherModel->relation()->first();
$relatedModel->pivot; // Pivot object
```

But for what you are trying to do simply use additional param in the `save` method:

```
$product = Product::find($item->id);
$order->product()->save($product, ['price' => 12.34]);
```

For existing relation:

```
$product = $order->product()->find($productId);
$product->pivot->price = 12.34;
$product->pivot->save();

// or
$order->product()->updateExistingPivot($productId, ['price'=>12.34]);
```

And I suggest you use `products` for that kind of relation in order to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

You should save() the pivot itself.

```
$order->pivot->price = '1.234';
$order->pivot->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel 5, you may want to use this syntax:

```php
$order->products()->attach($product, ['quantity' => 100]);
```

Where `quantity` is an attribute of pivot table.